# htmlentities function in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
$line=htmlentities(stripslashes($line));
```

This is the normal PHP statement.
Can anyone tell me the Syntax in javascript to perform the above task through javascript??

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't need to. Using `createTextNode` and friends, and avoiding `innerHTML` largely removes the need to worry about entities in JS.

Comment: You could possible use JQuery as answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Comment: The review above does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a library for this. It has an equivalent to PHP htmlentities function:
http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities/

Comment: Thanks @cclerville
I found htmlspecialcharacters js on the same website suggected by you.. and it's worksing perfectly. http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars/